# Using custom event to draw shapes in another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have 2 forms, Main Form & ModalBox.

In Main Form I have a button that when clicked draws a shape depending on the selected index of the comboBox.

```
// Create Rectangle or Ellipse 
  public void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        if (shapeSizeControl1.comboBoxShapeSelection.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(sb, Convert.ToSingle(shape.X), Convert.ToSingle(shape.Y), Convert.ToSingle(shape.Width), Convert.ToSingle(shape.Height));
        }
        else if (shapeSizeControl1.comboBoxShapeSelection.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(sb, Convert.ToSingle(shape.X), Convert.ToSingle(shape.Y), Convert.ToSingle(shape.Width), Convert.ToSingle(shape.Height));
        }
    }
```

In the ModalBox form I have an Ok button which should do the same thing as the button in Main Form but it doesn't because I have no idea how to program it to do so.

**What i've tried..**

1. Copying the same code from Main Form buttonAdd_Click into ModalBox buttonOk_Click. Bad idea because I have to instantiate a new Main form to get the panel1 variable. If I do that nothing happens. Why? I'm not sure an explanation would be great.
2. Creating a custom event so when the ModalBox Form opens, once I press the ok button since its subscribed It will draw the shape. **1 problem** I have no idea where to call the event and check for null because the button is on the second form so If I call the custom event in the first form I have no where to call the event and do null check.

**Goal**

My goal is to figure out how to add shapes in the Main Form from the ModalBox Form using the Ok button in the ModalBox Form.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method `DrawShape()` in the main form that draws your shapes and call it from the button click.

```
// Main Form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawShape();
}
```

Now create the modal form and set the owner

```
// Main form
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dlg = new ModalBox();

    if (dlg.ShowDialog(this)==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Finally in the modal form call the `DrawShape()` function

```
// Modal form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parent = this.Owner as MainForm;
    parent.DrawShape();
}
```

Comment: PS. To do this correctly you need to subscribe to the `Paint` event of the form and have the drawing done there.